# Configure duration of keeping results of HIVE queries in CDH?

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh, hue

I am using HUE for querying HIVE tables on CDH 5.13.3. The results are visible in HUE interface for approximately 3 hours, and after that they have "Result expired" status.
https://ibb.co/3CWNsJC
1.How can I configure Hive to keep the results for a longer period(ie. 1 day)?
2.Where are the results of the hive queries stored?(HDFS/local filesystem)
3.Are the results of the queries stored by HIVE or HUE?(I assume Hive)

Comment: please include the image in the question. can you show us your configuration so far?

Comment: https://ibb.co/3CWNsJC. Unfortunately i cannot share the configuration due to the policy of the company.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the idle queries open longer. The results are stored in HDFS by Hive so the overhead is not too big. It explained on the Hue blog about [query lifecycle](http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-hive-and-impala-queries-life-cycle/).

Comment: It turned out that i have these 3 values set -> https://ibb.co/zxCwm7s. hive.server2.session.check.interval = 15min, hive.server2.idle.operation.timeout=6h, hive.server2.idle.session.timeout = 6h. Unfortunately as I described the results are removed approximately after 3h, but sometimes much earlier(ie. 15 mins).